# How to stop sequelize from sending default value to MYSQL table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The console log:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `testtables` (`id`,`forgot_code`,`customer_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT,610,199)
```

How can I stop sequelize from sending `DEFAULT` value into my column `id` ? 
How can I stop sequelize from inserting into my Primary Key since it is already on auto increment ?

My code:

```
var TestTable= sequelize.define('testtables', {
    id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    forgot_code:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    customer_id:Sequelize.INTEGER   
},{
    timestamps: false,
});
```

Comment: I'm curious: is this actually causing a problem?  If so, what's the error? I don't typically write queries like this, but it seems like it would have exactly the same effect as not referencing the column in the insert statement at all (which implicitly inserts the "default" which is implicitly still `NULL` even though the column is `NOT NULL`) and should result in the next auto increment value being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late reply, but I had similar issue with Percona. So the solution for us was adding a hook:

```
new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  dialect: 'mysql',

  // FIXME: This is a temporary solution to avoid issues on Percona when Sequelize transform insert query into
  // INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] (`id`, ...) VALUES (DEFAULT, ...)
  hooks: {
    beforeCreate: ((attributes) => {
      if (attributes
        && attributes.dataValues
        && attributes.dataValues.hasOwnProperty('id')
      ) {
        delete attributes.dataValues.id
      }
    })
  },
})
```

**Update:** found this solution on DB level: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero

Answer (score 0):

1.delete all node modules
2.Re install node modules( npm install)

Now, issue will be fixed. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove `autoIncrement: true` from your model definition. Now, inserting without providing the `id` value will fail. For example, the below code will fail

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    // autoIncrement: true
  },
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => User.create({
    username: 'test123'
  }).then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  }));
```

However if you uncomment `autoIncrement: true`, insert will go through